# Account for all scenarios

Tags: javascript, if-statement

I currently have a really long script that will account for each scenario. I wrote it to move an AI either up, down, left or right on a board.

Including all the comments, my actual script is 448 lines long and really messy as most of the code is copied to account for each scenario. (Can be found [here](http://hastebin.com/itucimosuj.vhdl) if interested)

So you don't have to look through 448 lines of code, I have written some pseudo-code:

```
function ai() {
    var r = 0 or 1
    if condition

        if 0
            r = 0 or 1
            if 0
                if canDo c
                    do c
                else
                    if canDo d
                        do d
                    else
                        if canDo a
                            do a
                        else
                            if canDo b
                                do b
                            else
                                giveUp
            else if 1
                if canDo d
                    do d
                else
                    if canDo c
                        do c
                    else
                        if canDo a
                            do a
                        else
                            if canDo b
                                do b
                            else
                                giveUp
        else if 1
            r = 0 or 1
            if 0
                if canDo a
                    do a
                else
                    if canDo b
                        do b
                    else
                        if canDo c
                            do c
                        else
                            if canDo d
                                do d
                            else
                                giveUp
            else if 1
                if canDo b
                    do b
                else
                    if canDo a
                        do a
                    else
                        if canDo c
                            do c
                        else
                            if canDo d
                                do d
                            else
                                giveUp
    else

        if 0
            r = 0 or 1
            if 0
                if canDo c
                    do c
                else
                    if canDo d
                        do d
                    else
                        if canDo a
                            do a
                        else
                            if canDo b
                                do b
                            else
                                giveUp
            else if 1
                if canDo d
                    do d
                else
                    if canDo c
                        do c
                    else
                        if canDo a
                            do a
                        else
                            if canDo b
                                do b
                            else
                                giveUp
        else if 1
            r = 0 or 1
            if 0
                if canDo a
                    do a
                else
                    if canDo b
                        do b
                    else
                        if canDo c
                            do c
                        else
                            if canDo d
                                do d
                            else
                                giveUp
            else if 1
                if canDo b
                    do b
                else
                    if canDo a
                        do a
                    else
                        if canDo c
                            do c
                        else
                            if canDo d
                                do d
                            else
                                giveUp
}
```

**Is there an easier way of going about having multiple scenarios because as you can see it becomes quite long really quick?**

Comment: What does `r = 0 or 1` mean? And what does `if 0` mean? The body of an `if(0)` block will never execute. What is the condition you're using in `if condition`? I realize you're going for pseudocode here, but pseudocode still has to actually make sense in order to be useful.

Comment: @JLRishe It doesn't matter. What I'm asking is there an easy way to do multiple scenarios like this? If you really want to know look at my full function in the link provided.

Comment: No, it does matter whether your questions make sense, and the response would be "scenarios like what?" because it isn't remotely clear. I will look at your code, but please strive to provide code samples that clearly convey what you are trying to do.

Comment: Those a, b, c, ds are the same everywhere?

Answer (score 1):

The most important thing is to recognize where you have duplicate code (and you have a lot) and factor that out into reusable functions. Then this will often allow you to notice more duplicate code, which you can further factor out. And then you might notice code that's similar and that can be factored out into a more general case. This is what I came up with when I did this on your code:

```
function ai(charPos) {
    var r = getRandomInt(0, 1);
    if (aiPos[0] - pos[0] > (aiPos[1] - pos[1]) * 2) {
        // Horizontal distance shorter than vertical distance
        if (!isInLine(charPos, aiPos, 'vertical')) {
            tryVerticalThenHorizontal();
        } else {
            tryHorizontalThenVertical();
        }
    } else {
        // Vertical distance shorter than horizontal distance
        if (!isInLine(charPos, aiPos, 'horizontal')) {
            tryHorizontalThenVertical();
        } else {
            tryVerticalThenHorizontal();
        }
    }
}

function Move(name, dx, dy) {
    this.name = name;
    this.dx = dx;
    this.dy = dy;
}

var verticalMoves = [new Move("up", 0, -1), new Move("down", 0, 1)];
var horizontalMoves = [new Move("left", -1, 0), new Move("right", 1, 0)];

function tryVerticalThenHorizontal() {
    if (!(pickAndTryMoves(verticalMoves) || pickandTryMoves(horizontalMoves))) {
        aiShoot();
    }
}

function tryHorizontalThenVertical() {
    if (!(pickAndTryMoves(horizontalMoves) || pickAndTryMoves(verticalMoves))) {
        aiShoot();
    }
}

// Returns true if a move succeeded, false if not
// moves should be an array with two items, each of which is a Move 
function pickAndTryMoves(moves) {
    var option = getRandomInt(0, 1;

    // Try moves[option], and moves[otherOption] if the first one fails
    return tryMove(moves[option]) || tryMove(moves[1 - option]);
}

// move is a Move object
function tryMove(move) {
    var canMove = canAiMove(move.name);
    if (canMove) {
        moveAi(move.dx, move.dy, move.name);
    }

    return canMove;
}

function moveAi(dx, dy, dirName) {
    var x = aiPos[0], y = aiPos[1],
        nextX = x + dx, nextY = y + dy;
    map[nextY] = map[nextY].replaceAt(nextX, '2');
    map[y] = map[y].replaceAt(x, wallChar);
    aiPos[0] = nextX;
    aiPos[1] = nextY;
    aiLastDir = dirName;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You test for impossible conditions, and almost all of your code is just copy/pasted previous code. Turn these into functions, and organize them better.

Example of your impossible conditions:

```
if (r == 1) {
  do a
} else {
  if (r == 1) {
    do b
  } else {
    do c
  }
}
```

It is impossible to do b in this scenario, we can only get to the else statement if r does NOT equal 1, so why are we testing it again?

I formatted your same code into 40 lines. You will have to go through it but you can see how much easier something like this is to maintain and update:

```
function ai(charPos) {
    var r = getRandomInt(0, 1);
    var arrUp = [0, -1, 'up'], arrDown = [0, 1, 'down'], 
        arrLeft = [-1, 0, 'left'], arrRight = [1, 0 'right'];

    if (r == 1) {
        var horizontalArray = [arrRight, arrLeft, arrDown, arrUp];
        var verticalArray    = [arrUp, arrDown, arrLeft, arrRight];
    } else {
        var horizontalArray = [arrLeft, arrRight, arrUp, arrDown];
        var verticalArray    = [arrDown, arrUp, arrRight, arrLeft];
    }

    if (aiPos[0] - pos[0] > (aiPos[1] - pos[1]) * 2) {
        // Horizontal distance shorter than vertical distance
        if (!isInLine(charPos, aiPos, 'vertical')) ? move(verticalArray) : move(horizontalArray);
    } else {
        // Vertical distance shorter than horizontal distance
        if (!isInLine(charPos, aiPos, 'horizontal')) ? move(horizontalArray) : move(verticalArray);
    }
}

function directionalMove(directions) {
    if (canAiMove(directions[0][0])) {
        mappos(directions[0][0], directions[0][1], directions[0][2]);
    } else if (canAiMove(directions[1][0])) {
        mappos(directions[1][0], directions[1][1], directions[1][2]);
    } else if (canAiMove(directions[2][0])) {
        mappos(directions[2][0], directions[2][1], directions[2][2]);
    } else if (canAiMove(directions[3][0])) {
        mappos(directions[3][0], directions[3][1], directions[3][2]);
    } else {
        aiShoot();
    }
}

function mappos(x, y, name) {
        map[aiPos[1] + y] = map[aiPos[1] + y].replaceAt(aiPos[0] + x, '2');
        map[aiPos[1]] = map[aiPos[1]].replaceAt(aiPos[0], wallChar);
        aiPos[0] = aiPos[0] + x;
        aiPos[1] = aiPos[1] + y;
        aiLastDir = name;
}
```

Comment: There's a problem here. If `canAiMove(directions[0])` is `true`, it will move the AI down no matter what the value of `directions[0]` was.

Comment: @JLRishe Corrected... Nice catch. I think I ended up spending more time on this question than all other questions I've answered combined. Lol, nice solution by the way.

Comment: Thanks. :) It took up a lot of my time too. I think the problem I mentioned above is still there. You need a way of translating the direction name strings into X and Y delta values.

Comment: I cannot believe I did that... That's what I get for trying to scribble something quickly at 2AM... somewhat hideous quick fix w/ the multidimensional array but it works. I'm more than done with this question now. Lol